# Високосный год на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть рабочий код для определения того високосный год или нет. Вот:

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

if (year % 4) == 0:
    if (year % 100) == 0:
        if (year % 400) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True
else:
    return False

return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

И есть такой, но он не работает, только если год равен `1992`, а с другими годами все окей.

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    
if year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0:
    return True
else:
    return False

    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему. Разве они не идентичны? Почему первый рабочий полностью, а второй частично? Спасибо.

Comment: в питоне есть встроенная функция isleap в пакет calendar

Comment: во втором варианте не обрабатывается случай, когда год просто кратен четырём и не кратен 100.

Comment: @xmikex, а разве если на 100 делится без остатка, то он не считается високосным или я что-то не так понял? Спасибо

Comment: Если делится на 100, то высокосный только когда делится на 400. У вас этот случай проверяется. Не проверяется случай, когда просто делится на 4, но не делится на 100.

Comment: второй код не работает не только с 1992, но и со всеми годами не кратными 100 и 400

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем втором варианте високосными будут считаться **только** те года, которые делятся на 400, т.к. `True` вернется только если все три условия выполняются, а это случается только для тех лет, которые делятся на 400 (они автоматически делятся еще и на 4 и на 100).

Попробуйте так:

```
def is_leap(year):
    return year%4==0 and (year%100!=0 or year%400==0)
```

тесты:

```
In [168]: is_leap(2000)
Out[168]: True

In [169]: is_leap(2020)
Out[169]: True

In [170]: is_leap(2100) # если год делится на 100, но не делится на 400 - он НЕ является високосным
Out[170]: False
```

Comment: спасибо Вам. Получается, что какое-то из 3-х условий выполняться не должно, верно? Точно должно делиться на 4 и 400, а на 100 же автоматически тоже делится, тогда почему 1 решение там False возвращается когда на 4 делим без остатка?

Comment: @user9085541, по определению високосного года таковым считается год, который делится на 4 и не делится на 100 (исключением из второго правила является тот случай если число делится на 400). Т.е. 2000 - делится на 4, делится на 100 и делится на 400 - високосный. Другой пример 2100 - делится на 4 и (делится на 100, но НЕ делится на 400) - НЕ високосный.